# Stale file handles when copying files to network share (SMB) with std::fs::copy

Tags: linux, rust, samba

I've written a tiny program to copy files to a network share in a systematic manner in Rust using `std::fs::copy` to do the heavy lifting. The network share is a CIFS mount on Linux via samba. It used to use version one of the protocol (which has been deprecated a long while ago). The mount looked like this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o vers=1.0 //remote /mountpoint
```

The Rust code to copy the files looks something like this

```
std::fs::copy(source_file.path(), target_directory.join(source_file.file_name()))?;
```

This worked without a hitch.

The server software for the remote has been updated and I could drop the `vers=1.0` argument for the mount. Presumably it uses some more recent version now.

However, now the same program fails with the error:

```
Stale file handle (os error 116)
```

`strace` reports that opening the remote file for writing produced the error:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/origin/file", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
statx(4, "", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT|AT_EMPTY_PATH, STATX_ALL, {stx_mask=STATX_ALL|STATX_MNT_ID, stx_attributes=0, stx_mode=S_IFREG|0755, stx_size=30566455, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/remote_mountpoint/file", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0100755) = 5
statx(5, "", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT|AT_EMPTY_PATH, STATX_ALL, 0x7fffe81df6c0) = -1 ESTALE (Stale file handle)
```

So calling `statx` on a file handle that was just opened in the preceding call is suddenly "stale".

Do you know why, and how I could remedy this? Is it a bug in `std::fs::copy`?

I'm a bit out my depth here, but could this be because `std::fs::copy` tries to also copy metadata and with the new CIFS version that's somehow unsupported?

Note that copying using `std::fs::File` and `std::io::copy` works.

```
let mut source = fs::File::open(&source_file.path())?;
let mut target = fs::File::create(import_directory.join(source_file.file_name()))?;
std::io::copy(&mut source, &mut target)?;
```

**Here's the bit I don't understand at all**: this *also results in a stale file handle*, **but it works**. `strace` shows:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/origin/file", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/remote_mountpoint/file", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 5
statx(4, "", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT|AT_EMPTY_PATH, STATX_ALL, {stx_mask=STATX_ALL|STATX_MNT_ID, stx_attributes=0, stx_mode=S_IFREG|0755, stx_size=4590679, ...}) = 0
statx(5, "", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT|AT_EMPTY_PATH, STATX_ALL, 0x7fffc29e56e0) = -1 ESTALE (Stale file handle)
```

So the syscalls aren't made in the same *order* (`std::fs::copy` put its `statx` call *before* the second call to `openat`) but the end result is the same: `statx` on the remote file handle returns `-1 ESTALE`. But `std::fs::copy` aborts, and proceeds to write its error output to screen, and `std::io::copy` just happily continues to call `read` and `write` syscalls and ends up copying the file just fine.

I'm happy with this solution and have no reason to prefer `std::fs::copy` over `std::io::copy`, but I'd like to know the reason the former fails, and if the latter is my only option then.

Comment: My guess is that `fs::copy` actually needs the results of `statx` and `io::copy` doesn't and is therefore happy to continue. I still don't know why the stale file handle error occurs in the first place, though.

Comment: I suspect it's using `openat()` to avoid some race conditions that can lead to security holes, but CIFS doesn't implement it properly. Unix file descriptor concepts don't always map directly to some file sharing protocols.

Comment: My guess is it doesn't work properly when it's creating a new file, only when opening an existing file.

Comment: As for why the second test works, I suspect that Rust function ignores the error in `statx()`

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your input. In all cases, the files are created and do not exist before. I agree, the second way probably just isn't interested in the error condition of `statx`. I wonder why it needs to execute it at all.